# Helper function works in console but fails in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have the following helper function in ApplicationHelper class:

```
  def convert_to_range(n)
    [ (0..49), (50..99)].each do |range|
      if range.cover? (n)
        return "#{range.min}+"
      end
    end
  end
```

If I load this function to console, it works:

```
 convert_to_range 66 
 # 50+
```

However, when I call it from view, it returns

```
[0..49, 50..99]
```

What happens here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the same number coming from the view ?

Comment: What do you want returned in case `n` is not in the ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you are passing from your view must be out of the ranges you pass in. The default behavior then would be to return the last line of the method, but since the only statement is the for, it returns what that evaluates to, which is your Array of two Range objects.

```
irb(main):013:0> convert_to_range 45
=> "0+"
irb(main):016:0> convert_to_range 99
=> "50+"
irb(main):014:0> convert_to_range 100
=> [0..49, 50..99]
```

If you add a return statement to signify an error, you will get that instead of your array:

```
def convert_to_range(n)
    [(0..49), (50..99)].each do |range|
      if range.cover? (n)
        return "#{range.min}+"
      end
    end

    false
end

irb(main):025:0> convert_to_range  999
=> false
```

or you could optionally raise an exception.